# Bootstrap required validation to select one of the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have this fiddle (from my project) https://jsfiddle.net/autofiddle/cap6g9wq/20/

I want to have customer name and the first dropdown required as it is.

Depending on what you choose in the first dropdown, another dropdown with numbers is displayed.

I want to validate errors (display div id = "quantity-zero") when you click the button if all the dropdown is 0. If any dropdown is more than 0, the validation is ok.

I have tested like this (think there is a better way) but its not working and I want to connect it to bootstrap validation and don't just make the div visible in the loop below.

```
var totalQuantity = 0;

$(".quantity-select").each(function () {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) === 0) {
        //display the bootstrap error.
        //don't want it like this: $( "#quantity-zero" ).show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate your form by using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), you don't need to add **required** on tag, just by adding some rules like the code below :

```
$("#order-form").validate({
    rules: {
        customerName: "required",
        caseSelect: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        customerName: "Please enter a customer namn.",
        caseSelect: "You need to select a quantity for your case.",
    }
});
```

try this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g5y9ho3x/

Comment: If you select case 2 in the first dropdown and let the second new visible dropdown still be zero you don't get any validation error. when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

The select does not have a value. You should get the value from the selected option, probably something like this:

```
$(".quantity-select option:selected").val();
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to check all the visible dropdowns you can use the following code:

```
$('.quantity-select:visible').each(function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').val();
});
```

The `$(this).find('option:selected').val();` is the value of the selected dropdown. So you can make a check in the each statement and maybe set a var to true or false depending on the value.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but my real problem is to connect that all number dropdown is 0 to native boottrap validation. One of the 3 dropdown is required, or more than 0. If not I want to fail bootstrap validation.

Comment: @Xtreme I don't understand the problem? Why should all dropdowns have a value > 0? Because there is a dropdown shown based on the case selection right?

Comment: I have updated https://jsfiddle.net/autofiddle/cap6g9wq/23/ the validation pass if one of the two visible dropdown is more than one. If both of the visible dropdown i 0 the validation fail.
I just used one to make it simple. I have more than one visible dropdown at time and at lest one of the visible needs to be more than one to pass the validation.

Comment: @Xtreme see updated answer. Maybe this helps you in the right direction.